# How to draw a graphviz spline in d3

Tags: d3.js, graphviz, dot, spline, cubic-spline

#### Background

graphviz is great for laying out graphs. When I layout my graph with graphviz "dot" it produces a file with nodes and edges tagged with positions. E.g. an edge:

```
"a" -> "b"   [pos="e,152.13,411.67 91.566,463.4 108.12,449.26 127.94,432.34 144.37,418.3"];
```

The [Graphviz spline language](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#k:splineType) is the following:

> ```
>  spline       =   (endp)? (startp)? point (triple)+
>  and triple   =   point point point
>  and endp     =   "e,%f,%f"
>  and startp   =   "s,%f,%f"
> ```
>
> If a spline has points `p1 p2 p3 ... pn`, (n = 1 (mod 3)), the points correspond to the control points of a cubic B-spline from `p1` to `pn`. If `startp` is given, it touches one node of the edge, and the arrowhead goes from `p1` to `startp`. If `startp` is not given, `p1` touches a node. Similarly for `pn` and `endp`.

So decomposing the string above,

```
e,152.13,411.67   // This is an endpoint. 
91.566,463.4      // p1
108.12,449.26     // the following three points are control points for a cubic b-spline
127.94,432.34
144.37,418.3
```

#### Question

I want to draw this spline via d3. d3 seems to have [cubic b-splines](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curveBasis) with the following signature:

> **d3.curveBasis(context)**
>
> Produces a cubic basis spline using the specified control points. The first and last points are triplicated such that the spline starts at the first point and ends at the last point, and is tangent to the line between the first and second points, and to the line between the penultimate and last points.

So how do I take the string

```
[pos="e,152.13,411.67 91.566,463.4 108.12,449.26 127.94,432.34 144.37,418.3"];
```

And draw the spline that graphviz would draw in d3?

Comment: directly construct the `d` attribute of the path with the SVG spline commands `C` and `Q`. Write a function that transforms the GraphViz string to an SVG path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was overthinking this.

If you move the `e` (endpoint) to the end of the array of points, `d3.curveBasis()` renders this perfectly.

```
# G is a networkx graph and A is a pygraphviz graph
for e in G.edges():
    points = A.get_edge(e[0], e[1]).attr["pos"].lstrip('e,').split(' ')
    points.append(points.pop(0))
    G.edges[e[0], e[1]].update({'points': [{'x':float(p.split(',')[0]), 'y':float(p.split(',')[1])} for p in points]})
```

And later:

```
var lineGenerator = d3.line().y(d => d.y).x(d => d.x).curve(d3.curveBasis);

link.enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', l => lineGenerator(l.points))
```